# How to swap two LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a parent Linear Layout inside which there are two Linear Layout and a button.Each Linear Layout inside the parent Linear layout has two items in it. Items include a edit text and a spinner.what I want is to swap this two LinearLayout when i click the button.So my question is How do i do that programatically?. I am new to Android development so please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your outermost LinearLayout, try calling removeViewAt(0). This should remove the first LinearLayout. Then call addView() passing it the first LinearLayout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the point is I don't want to hide any layout. I just want to change each other's position. Each layout taking the position of the other layout when clickd on the button. For example layout one will go to layout two's position and layout two will come to layout 1's position I hope I could make you understand what I want.

Comment: Thanks Karim Varela. The solution worked well. Swapping is working jus t fine now. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to just make two layouts.  Designed such that when you are ready to use the other one, switch layouts and then set that as the current view.

Or you could do so with various animation classes if trying to get fancy with it.  If there is an exact visual effect you are trying to receive, perhaps provide a bit more on what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, did you mean creating replica of the parent layout and then switch between these layouts. If that's so, will you please tell me the way how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As Karim mentioned, you can use setVisibilty() to View.GONE and the to View.VISIBLE.
But for a smooth swapping you are going to need to learn about [Translate Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example of how to swap two views (e.g. two LinearLayouts):

```
ViewGroup root = findViewById(R.id.my_root);
// assumption: root has 2 child views only 
// swap left and right (or top and bottom)
View leftView = root.getChildAt(0);
root.removeViewAt(0);
root.addView(leftView);
// now the two child views of root are swapped
```